# xCode error 'RNGoogleSignin/RNGoogleSignin.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, react-native

I installing react-native-google-signin but after I clean and build I get an error in my appdelegate.m saying `'RNGoogleSignin/RNGoogleSignin.h' file not found`. I installed and reinstalled several times via manual using the guide https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin/blob/master/ios-guide.md.

Using xcode 9

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: did you get the solution. please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Check if the things are placed properly.

1. Google Info Plist is in the Root Folder.
2. Google IOS SDK is added in the frameworks folder - https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/
3. Update URL Types in the Info Panel.
4. Add this code .

> ```
>    // add this line before @implementation AppDelegate
> #import <RNGoogleSignin/RNGoogleSignin.h>
>
> // add this method before @end
> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
>   sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
>
>   return [RNGoogleSignin application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
> }
> ```

5. Clean the Project
6. Build Again